# Present Participles: can "respicienti" be part of an ablative absolute in this sentence?

Tags: classical-latin, morphology, participle, suetonius, ablative-absolute

Suetonius, *Caius* (Caligula) 58:

> ...alii Sabinum summota per conscios centuriones turba signum more militiae petisse et Caio "lovem" dante Chaeream exclamasse: "accipe ratum" respicientique maxillam ictu discidisse.

The present participle, *respicienti(que),* is it linked to the ablative absolute *Caio dante*—with Caligula giving; continuing—with Caligula looking up; if so, *respicienti* would require the case-ending "e", not "i"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sumelic says, both *-i* and *-e* can be used as the ablative ending of a participle. Even so, mixing them in the same sentence would probably be unusual.

*Respicienti* is really a dative here; the new a.c.i. (*discidisse*) has a different construction from the previous one (*exclamasse* with an ablative absolute *Caio dante*). The new construction is like *Chaerea [Gaio] respicienti maxillam discidit*: "Chaerea split (for) him his jaw when he looked back". The archetype is *alicui maxillam discindere*: to split the jaw for someone = to split someone's jaw.

Cf.  Suetonius, *De Vita Caesarum Aug*. 67.2.4:

> Thallo a manu, quod pro epistula prodita denarios quingentos accepisset, **crura ei fregit**; ...

"He broke his (Thallus's) legs", with dative *ei*.

Comment: Cerberus: Thanks (yet) again: taking "respicienti" as  dative gives "Chaerea split the jaw, with a blow, to/ for Caius, he-who-was-looking-back" a relative clause but it fits.

Comment: @tony: Yes, exactly!